# login to specific db via controller for odoo

Tags: python, odoo

am trying to login to odoo  through the controller

```
 @http.route('/ehs/login', methods=['POST'], auth='public', csrf=False)
 def login(self,**kwargs):
    username = kwargs.get('username')
    password = kwargs.get('password')
    db = kwargs.get('db')
    uid = request.session.authenticate(db, username,password) 

    if uid:
        user_id=request.env['res.partner'].search([('id','=',int(uid))])
        data={'uid':uid,'company_number':user_id.company_id.phone}
        jsondata = json.dumps(data)
        return jsondata
    else:
        return "wrong credential"
```

the above service is work fine if am having only One DB, it will show error when I try to log in to different Db in the same instance

Can any One help me? any help would be appreciated . ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

Add the addon you made this development to the `server_wide_modules` section in `odoo.conf`

```
server_wide_modules = base,web,YOUR_EXAMPLE_MODULE
```